# Vaadin double click and browser behavior

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, vaadin

I'm developing a Vaadin application (with version 6.8.10) with a **tree component**. We need to react to item's double clicks. But in our cross-browser tests we founded that the **double-click** doesn't work always in **Firefox** (some times works).

Here our eventListener code:

```
 @Override
  public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
  *  if (event.isDoubleClick()) {  // Breakpoint line
       // our action
    }
  }
```

Debugging in Eclipse we received following values (in each browser after a double click Vaadin receives 2 events)

**Chrome**

1° event received

> event.getButton()     ==>  1
>
> event.isDoubleClick() ==>  false
>
> event.getButtonName() ==>  left

2° event received

> event.getButton()     ==>  1
>
> event.isDoubleClick() ==>  **true**
>
> event.getButtonName() ==>  left

**Firefox**

1° event received

> event.getButton()     ==>  1
>
> event.isDoubleClick() ==>  false
>
> event.getButtonName() ==>  left

2° event received

> event.getButton()     ==>  1
>
> event.isDoubleClick() ==>  **false**
>
> event.getButtonName() ==>  left

**Resuming, in Firefox my double-click are detected as 2 single clicks!!!!**

Are you experienced something similar? Do you have a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try the code at https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/608272 to see whether the first or the second click is failing.  You might want to post on the Vaadin boards (if one of the existing posts isn't you).  And it looks like Vaadin has had some trouble in this area, after searching their boards.

Comment: Thanks Atk! That bug should be fixed in Version 6.6 and I'm using 6.8.10! And that forum post has more than 2 years. In Chrome the second event (of the double-click) is detected as double click! As you says it seems that Vaadin hat troubles with this area. I hope someone find a workaround or an official fix

Comment: Tano, good luck.  I'm not enough of a Vaadin expert to help further, but I hope either it gets fixed or someone comes along who can help you more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!

We saw that there is an old [Ticket (#8384)](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/8384) on Vaadin Forum who describes this behavior.

The proposed solution was to **setImmediate(false)** on the tree object, but we wanted to leave our code cleaner and we decided to remove the line **<s>setImmediate()</s>** from the code. We tested that `new Tree().isImmediate() == false` (as default), so it should work.

After a lot of testing, research and debugging... I decided to actually write **setImmediate(false)** im our code (it should be not necessary) and **magically now, our code works fine in Firefox!!!**

I hope this will be helpful to someone.